# Get the packets during the SSH handshake in batches

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, handshake

Get the packets during the SSH handshake in batches, and then extract the temporary key pairs and other data in it for analysis.How to extract the data in the handshake process in batches is a great difficulty. I have not found a corresponding method until now, or extract the data in the key negotiation process.

Answer (score 1):

Following "[Hacking-with-Go / SSH client](https://github.com/parsiya/Hacking-with-Go/blob/master/content/04.4.md)", I would use [Go](https://golang.org/) to get the `ssh.PublicKey` of the remote server.

See "[Some notes on using Go to check and verify SSH host keys](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoSSHHostKeyCheckingNotes)" by [Chris Siebenmann](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/)

That would extract the public key during the [SSH Handshake](https://gravitational.com/blog/ssh-handshake-explained/).